# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application .ApplicationDetails:

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Only Mi pad having that issue when run the app. 
For fix that issues i have  try 
1. Uninstall the app and retry to connect that but get same error
2. Instant run is disable in my android studio
3. User Multi desk in build gradle

Other project is working from same android studio in same tab

Any one Have idea how to fix that .

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.uncommonsense, PID: 23808
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application .application.ApplicationDetails: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ".application.ApplicationDetails" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.uncommonsense-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ucsvirtualschool.application.ApplicationDetails" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.uncommonsense-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.uncommonsense-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
```

Application class

```
public class ApplicationDetails extends MultiDexApplication {


    public static boolean isAppOpen = false;

    private static ApplicationDetails mInstance;
    public static final String TAG = ApplicationDetails.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        MultiDex.install(this);
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onTerminate();
        isAppOpen = false;
    }
}
```

build gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ucsvirtualschool"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables { useSupportLibrary = true    }
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
        }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //for solve issue in mi tab
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think of two things based on the code snippets you provided.

1. You already use the MultiDexApplication so you don't need to override the attachBaseContext method
2. It might happen, but very unlikely that the ApplicationDetails class doesn't make it to the first dex file and that's why the app is crashing. You could try to declare the class to be required to be in the very first dex file. [Declare classes required in the primary dex file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Comment: previously i have use only Application when i get this issue then add multidex and use MultiDexApplication  .                                                                                                now i am try your suggestion but issue not solve

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this: complete the application name "`.application.ApplicationDetails`" with "`com.ucsvirtualschool.application.ApplicationDetails`" in your in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application
    android:name="com.ucsvirtualschool.application.ApplicationDetails"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
```

Comment: Hi, Please follow some guidelines from the help page. The fix provided in your answer might work, but this is hard to human interpret if someone is new. Please reformat and provide context.

Comment: Thanks for you advisement. I'm not sure if it is ok now